# How can I do gapless audio looping with mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

It seems I'm unable to achieve gapless looping with mobile. This is what I've done so far:

https://github.com/Hivenfour/SeamlessLoop

- Creates a gap.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/

- Creates a gap.

https://github.com/regosen/Gapless-5

- Creates a gap.
- Downloads same audio twice.

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

- Creates a gap.

HTML5 audio

- Creates a gap.

Cordova's media plugin

- Creates a gap.

WebAudio

- WORKS!
- For 1.5min audio clip, decoding time is > 30 seconds.
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424174

All above tested with mp3 and ogg.

EDIT:

SoundJS's cordova plugin is broken and thus doesn't work;

https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues/170

Comment: you could preload a 2nd copy, play the 1st, watch the position, and play the 2nd ~200ms before the 1st ends. might need tweaking on the delay, or maybe somehow compute it from a benchmark...

Comment: I'm afraid this and crossfading seems to be the only possible solutions. Your suggestion has problems when the delay is not the same for all platforms and devices. Crossfading is good on certain sounds but really bad on others.

Comment: yeah, you can probably measure the delay/lag with a silent track, but you're right, it's not going to be perfect. it might be passable or better than nothing or a hot phone though... there's also the issue of trailing silence, which might be work-around-able with CORS and API to load the tail and find the last audible content.

Comment: I might have to resort to using a long track (like 8min+) and just leaving the gap there and hope no-one notices. :/. I wish webaudio's decode wasn't so slow, since it's the only one that loops perfectly.

Comment: you might want to bounty this for more exposure, i would like to see a good solution.

Comment: Can you provide your test files ?

Comment: dandavis, I did bounty it, a week ago. No-one answered. :( c97, I've deleted most of them as I figured out they don't work gapless.

Comment: Did you tried my answer again, I updated it with another option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With HTML5
>   If you are using HTML5, then use loop attribute.

```
<audio controls loop>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

It doesn't create gap, check with your audio file, most of the audio file has gap at the end.

You can test it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all), just add loop attribute and run the page.

> With JavaScript

Here is also an alternative by using javascript

```
myAudio = new Audio('someSound.ogg'); 
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
myAudio.play();
```

Here JavaScript will create little gap, you can overcome it by playing loop not when audio is finished but when audio is about to finish.
Here is code.

> Here is what you want.

```
myAudio = new Audio('http://unska.com/audio/pinknoise.ogg'); 
myAudio.ontimeupdate= function(i) {
  if((this.currentTime / this.duration)>0.9){
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
  }
};
myAudio.play();
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hcuxsMkAcUuTz70IsAhz?p=preview) is Demo.

Comment: Are you serious? HTML audio creates the worst gap of them all http://unska.com/audio/htmlaudio.html 

The javascript version creates a nasty gap too http://unska.com/audio/javascriptaudio.html

Comment: Also, if you want to show how to do a gapless playback loop, use a soundfile that's gapless itself, not a horse sound with silence at the beginning and end on the file.

Comment: I'm going to ask the moderators if they can still give you the bounty eventhough it run out yesterday.

Comment: If you have a gap in your audio, try `this.currentTime = 0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party here, but I've got a gapless solution with `https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio`

Not the most beautiful implementation -- but it works completely gapless:

> Javascript

```
const LOOP_INTERVAL = 5000

window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex( 'loop1', getMediaURL('media/loop.mp3'), 1, 1, 0, function(msg){
  }, function(msg){
    console.log( 'error: ' + msg );
  });

window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex( 'loop2', getMediaURL('media/loop.mp3'), 1, 1, 0, function(msg){
  }, function(msg){
    console.log( 'error: ' + msg );
  });

function startGaplessLoop () {
  var flag = false;
  setInterval(function() {
     flag = !flag
     window.plugins.NativeAudio.play(flag ? 'loop2' : 'loop1') 
     setTimeout(function() {
      window.plugins.NativeAudio.stop(flag ? 'loop1' : 'loop2')
    }, 30)
  }, LOOP_INTERVAL)

  window.plugins.NativeAudio.play('loop1')
}

startGaplessLoop()
```

Don't forget to stop the interval and unload the sound when you're finished!

Answer (score -1):

Try [SoundJS](http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/modules/SoundJS.html). It includes a [cordova plugin](http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/CordovaAudioSoundInstance.html).

Comment: I already notified them that their plugin does not work: https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues/170